# Connect Azure-hosted Ruby on Rails app to on-premise SQL Server through Windows Azure Connect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, azure, connect

**What I've learned:**
  1. activerecord-sqlserver-adapter can be used to connect a RoR app to an SQL Server by simply changing the database.yml file. Much respect to Ken Collins (http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2011/modern-sql-server-rails/)
  2. Nick Hill has showed us how to host a RoR app in a Windows Azure web role
(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2010/02/26/9969876.aspx)
  3. Wely Lau, in "How to establishing virtual network connection between cloud and on-premise with Windows Azure Connect (Part 2–Preparing the application)", has showed us how to setup a virtual network connection between a Windows Azure web role and an on-premise SQL server with Windows Azure Connect. Specifically, Wely establishes the on-premise SqlDataSource in step 2 and 3 of her article. I would post a link, but i'm such a newb to stackoverflow, that i'm only allowed to post 2 links :(

**Anyway, what I'm trying to figure out:**
  4. How to connect a RoR app, hosted in a Windows Azure web role, to an on-premise SQL Server using a virtual network connection with Windows Azure Connect (i don't think it's as simple as changing the database.yml file to point to the on-premise database unfortunately)

I feel like the ingredients are there, but can't figure out how to cook the meal so to speak. For some context, my app users are grouped into teams and it's necessary that teams be able to specify exactly where their databases reside (e.g. either in the cloud or on one of their own servers) - hence the RoR/Azure thing, otherwise, Heroku would be my host.

An alternative I've been considering is to distribute a separate copy of the app for those teams who wish to use their own databases and host it themselves, in which case, i'm all set. However, I fear that could become messy quickly as I think about future updates and developer happiness.

Appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you've got Connect set up (mostly consists of installing the agent on your database server), it should indeed be as simple as changing database.yml. Why do you think it's harder than that?

Comment: I am not that far in the dev process as of yet and am trying to anticipate potential problems. So your feedback is very helpful. This question was also to help me determine how to setup a system with multiple databases. Are you a proponent of multiple instances of the app hosted at subdomains according to team? or one app code base at mysite.com that has "establish_connection on user log in" type logic?

Comment: That's a classic multi-tenant design question... generally, one instance of the app per "customer" has better isolation (and is often easier to develop) but worse utilization. If you want best price-performance, build a fully multi-tenant app that chooses the database based on the user.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem will be network latency (ie. long timeouts) and connection failures on the on-premise side, not setting up Azure Connect. You should at least consider using a SQL Azure database that syncs with your on-premise db. This will also be cheaper in terms of bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. This is an issue that has been on the back of my mind for sure. My team sizes are small however, at most 10 people, so those teams who choose to have on premise databases will have at most 10 users accessing them. For further context, the app is basically a blog, where users post and retrieve notes. Do you think given this scenario, the latency from the on-premise database would make the app unusable (say latency > 3 secs)? Would be curious if @smarx has any thoughts here too. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The Latest v3 SQL Server Adapter now supports Azure
http://groups.google.com/group/rails-sqlserver-adapter/browse_thread/thread/50dc2108c4fda584?hl=en

You must use the latest DBLIB/TinyTDS connection mode which also means you must use the latest FreeTDS compiled with OpenSSL. All the details are here.

https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-Azure
https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTDS

Comment: Much appreciated on this end. Right on!